# how to keep the text indentation same as user written in the <textarea>

Tags: php, html, mysql, forum

i am using php.my project is to build a forum...everything is fine and ok except onething...there is a `<textarea>` on top of my site,through which user can ask their question..now am using `insert into` command to insert whatever user has wriiten in textarea and `select` command to fetch the posts from database and the display it using `echo` command

**problem :  unable to keep the user's text indentation intact**

suppose user has written

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<conio.h>
 int main()
 {
    ...and so on;
  }
```

this code in the text area,while am displaying it through echo then the output is like

`#include<stdio.h>#include<conio.h>int main(){...and so on;}`

**so my question is how can i keep the text indentation of user intact**

**edit 1:my insertion code**

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/db.inc.php' ;
$myemail=$z;
$sem=$_POST['semester'];
$course=$_POST['course'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$desc=$_POST['question'];
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sem = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $sem);
$course = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $course);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $title);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $desc);
$sql =  "INSERT INTO wbut_forum_posts SET post_title='$title',post_desc='$desc',course='$course',semester='$sem',post_by='$myemail',post_date='$date'";
if (!mysqli_query($link,$sql))
{
include_once "wall.html.php";
echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"SOMETHING WENT WRONG, TRY AGAIN LATER !!!\");</script>"; 
exit();
}
else
{
include_once 'wall.html.php';
echo "<script language=javascript> alert(\"YOUR POST SUCCESSFULLY HAS BEEN POSTED\");        </script>";
exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a straight text area, try a WYSIWYG editor like tinyMCE, after playing with the settings a bit you will be able to get it to create the HTML of what the users enter, so you can get line breaks to convert to `<br>` tags and tabs to convert to `&nbsp;`(x4) or x8 or whatever you want. You can also remove all the controls to so it won't necessarily look like a WYSIWYG editor.

EDIT:
WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) - tinyMCE (http://www.tinymce.com/) is one such editor. You can follow the directions on their site, but it basically loads from JS and overrides your text areas with their editor. When the user clicks save or whatever (you tell tinyMCE via JS that the user is done) it will take their text as you see it and convert it to html, that converted text is what you would store in your DB. Since it's html being stored, all the line breaks and white spaces are preserved. A tool like this does require some JS skills to implement, try it and see what problems you come up against. This is kind of an overkill solution. But if you get tinyMCE properly set up it will give you complete control of what gets stored in your DB.

Comment: am sorry..i have no knowledge about it..what is this `WYSIWYG`]...how to use it in html??....**NOTE:** my actual problem while am inserting the data in database that moment the indentation is changing..can i stop it by using `WYSIWYG`..if yes how?????

Comment: @SarthokBhattacharya - See edit above. Too big for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Echo it out wrapped in `<pre>` tags or any tag with `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap`.  Use `htmlspecialchars` on it too.

Comment: will it work???..because when am inserting the post into the databse..the indentation changes then...so will it be effective to use <pre> while fetching from database?????

Comment: @SarthokBhattacharya why do you change the indentation when you insert it into the database?

Comment: this is not effective..i have tried just now..things have got even worse..because now some part of text in corner,some in left,some on right and the rest on middle..not working..

Comment: please tell me..how to keep the indentation intact while inserting it into the database???

Comment: @SarthokBhattacharya please post the code where you get the data from http and store it in the DB; there should be nothing that changes the indentation at storage time

Comment: ............i have edited it???...have you noticed any error???..what should i do??

Answer (score 1):

try this and see if it does the trick

```
echo str_replace(array("\t","    "),"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $text);
```

also try

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: he need the formatting when he uses `echo` function how is this not the answer ?

Comment: In general, when you use "have you tried" that means you're asking a question. Which should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a simpler alternative that may work for you. add a function to your form onSubmit() that will simply encode your text area so you are storing JS encoded text in your DB, something like `document.getElementById('textArea').value = encodeURI(document.getElementById('textArea').value);`

Then you would just need to parse that text to display it correctly, which I beleive php does with the urldecode() function. Though if you need to convert it to HTML to display correctly you might just need to do some regEx replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Good solution is to use editor as suggested above. this is very easy you just have to download package, include js, css etc and then bind your textarea with editor. I have used ckeditor(http://ckeditor.com/).
what it dows is it converts your test to html. also provide much more functionality like font color, font size underline, bold, italic and many more. You can check this out.